# ScheduledExecutorService running many threads when I created it using Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

### Context:

- This is a `Jersey` application
- Run on a `Tomcat` server
- Connects to a `MySQL` database using `Hibernate`
- All on `Netbeans`

I'm creating a `ScheduledExecutorService` to run everyday at a particular time. However, when it runs it creates many connections to the database. I imagine it's because the threads aren't being destroyed when I rerun the application, so many `ScheduledExecutorService`s build up in the JVM and all execute at the same time. But, I'm not sure what the cause is.

I create the `ScheduledExecutorService` with a `ThreadFactory` that only creates daemon threads, so when I rerun the application I imagine that all daemon threads should be destroyed so that only one `ScheduledExecutorService` ever exists.

Here is the creation of the `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }
    });
```

Here is how it runs everyday at a particular time:

```
public void startExecutionAt(int targetHour, int targetMin, int targetSec){
        long delay = computeNextDelay(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);

        mExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread t = new Thread(new CustomRunnable());
                t.setDaemon(false);
                t.start();
                startExecutionAt(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);
            }
        }, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

I know it's creating many connections to `MySQL` because in the `P6Spy` log there are many many connections and queries made when `CustomRunnable` is executed when `CustomRunnable` only runs one `Hibernate` query that selects 5 records from a table.

Any ideas as to what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously misuse your `ScheduledExecutorService`, here is what you are supposed to do:

```
public void startExecutionAt(int targetHour, int targetMin, int targetSec){
    long delay = computeNextDelay(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);

    mExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new CustomRunnable(), 
        1000L * delay, 
        TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1), 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    );
}
```

You call this method once for all and it will launch your task with `delay` as initial delay then every day at the same exact time.

More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Indeed you currently create a new thread any time the task is executed then call again the method to schedule the next execution which is not what you are supposed to do, the task is already executed in a pool no need to create a new `Thread` moreover no need to schedule again manually when you can do it directly with the `ScheduledExecutorService`.

**Response Update:**

As the scheduling seems to be more complicated in your case, here is how you should do it instead:

```
public void startExecutionAt(int targetHour, int targetMin, int targetSec){
    long delay = computeNextDelay(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);

    mExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new CustomRunnable().run();
            } finally {
                startExecutionAt(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);
            }
        }
    }, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

This way you won't create and start new threads for nothing.

The second part of your problem should be fixed by starting and shutting down properly your `ScheduledExecutorService` respectively on `ServletContext` initialized and destroyed, in other words the class that manages your scheduler should be a `ServletContextListener`.

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                return t;
            }
        });
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    public void startExecutionAt(int targetHour, int targetMin, int targetSec){
        // code defined above here
    }
}
```

If you need services to make it work, use CDI to get them by injection.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it takes into account daylight savings time

Comment: Also, shouldn't daemon threads terminate when I rerun my application ie redeploy? Right now I'm developing and constantly rerunning my application. The reason I created the `ScheduledExecutorService` with a `ThreadFactory` that only creates daemon threads was because I thought daemon threads should terminate when the program is redeployed; but that's not what's happening. Do you know what about the above code is preventing that from happening?

Comment: you also need to get a reference for the `ScheduledFuture` that's created by calling `executorService.schedule()`, and cancel it in `contextDestroyed()`. `executorService.shutdown()` doesn't cancel non-repetitive tasks by default